# Any advice on the textbooks used for calculus part of GRE Math Subject test

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation, advice

I've read some posts in the internet that to prepare the GRE Math Subject test, one has to go through all questions the Stewart's Calculus book. I have a copy of the Thomas' Calculus, which is quite heavy and contains tons of questions. I am not quite sure if there's any difference between using Stewart's or Thomas' in preparing for the exam, because to me, both are focusing on the application side of Calculus. Is it fine to use Thomas' Calculus instead of Stewart's.

Also is it fine to use Apostol's book for preparation.

My point is that if there's no difference between Stewart's and Thomas', then I would spend the money somewhere else because both are 1000+ pages and I don't really want too many books on the similar topics.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do graduate work, it would be bizarre to spend any time reading non-rigorous books like Stewart and Thomas.

I think Vols. 1 and 2 of Apostol cover the calculus part of the GRE well, but the page count is a problem.

I presume you've studied most of this material previously, so the problem will be to zero in on the parts you don't know as well. I would probably buy a GRE prep book with practice tests to identify the subjects I had difficulty with. Then I would read Apostol on those subjects only.

Comment: The test is 50% calculus and is multiple choice, hence doesn't require rigor for the most part, so I don't think reviewing Stewart is a waste of time.  I think it would be good to review a broad range of topics covered by the test in a pragmatic way rather than be overly concerned about rigor.

Comment: @JairTaylor You're right- I remember taking the GRE. But I also know that, particularly for some of the harder questions, a higher level of maturity than in Stewart and Thomas is needed. For someone going to graduate school, I don't see any advantage in Stewart over Apostol.

Comment: I should add that if you do choose to use Thomas, the earlier editions were much smaller.

Comment: @Anonymous hi, you mentioned smaller of earlier editions of Thomas in terms of the size of the book or in terms of the range? I got a copy of 11 Ed and it seems to have quite many questions..

Comment: Smaller in terms of the number of pages. I expect-but this is something you'll need to check-that most of the additions will have been related to fields of application rather than substantial additional mathematical content.